# Deploying smart contract with truffle and infura giving me error

Tags: truffle, ropsten, infura

I am having trouble deploying my smart contract to the ropsten network using infura and truffle am getting error that says

```
"var sig = secp256k1.sign(msgHash, privateKey);
                      ^
TypeError: private key should be a Buffer"
```

Comment: can you share some code / link of a tutorial you used ?

Comment: It appears you are passing an incorrect format for privateKey. If you have the hexadecimal private key you should pass as raw bytes instead `const privateKey = Buffer.from("ab1a..", "hex");`

Answer (score 0):

You can find how to deploy a contract using truffle and infura as it is explained [truffle documentation](https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider)

I copied the deployment code that I already owned below,

```
// Allows us to use ES6 in our migrations and tests.
require('babel-register')

const HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider-privkey");

const privateKey = "PRIVATEKEYADDRESS"; // private keys

module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // for more about customizing your Truffle configuration!
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
    rinkeby: {
      provider: () => {
        return new HDWalletProvider(privateKey, "https://rinkeby.infura.io/INFURAAPIKEY")
      },
      network_id: 4
    }
  }
};
```

Hope it works for you as well

Comment: Mehmet Dogan Thanks for the help but am still getting another error it outputs Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Comment: You share little with us and want to get full answer. But as far I know, this error is encountered when you try to deploy an Interface which includes unimplemented functions like ERC20Interface. 
Assuming that you try to deploy a contract named *myContract* 
`contract myContract is ERC20Interface {
..
}`
Then you just need to include myContract in your 2_deploy_contracts.js file

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 'from' address in lower case while deploying the contract to test network inorder to avoid this error.

Comment: Your answer is unrelated to the question asked.

Comment: Give a try. Actually, it worked for me and hence I responded!!

Comment: The function used [`secp256k1.sign`](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/secp256k1-node) doesn't accept a from parameter.

Comment: If you are deploying your contract like this for example: SampleContract.new(abcd, {from: '0xAD123EFG456...'}).then(function(){});           then the from address should be in small letters like SampleContract.new(abcd, {from: '0xad123efg456...'}).then(function(){});

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Ismael saying the function sepc256k1.sign won't need from parameter. worked for me without private keys declaration and from parameter